# Analog of Anderson localization caused by random hopping

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tight-binding, anderson-localization

Consider the tight-binding Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \sum_i \epsilon_i a^\dagger_i a_i + \sum_i V_i (a^\dagger_i a_{i+1} + a^\dagger_{i+1} a_i)
$$
Random on-site energy $\epsilon_i$ leads to the famous Anderson localization.
I wonder if there's an analog localization with random hopping $V_i$. I've carried out some numeric tests and the wavefunction seems to be localized.

Comment: Nice question. I suggest changing the title to _Analog of Anderson localization caused by random hopping_. Also in the text, _hopping_ is more appropriate than _electronic coupling_, in my opinion. Moreover, this is probably equally relevant for any fermion or boson.

Comment: @fra_pero Thanks for your advice. I've made the modification.

Comment: I'm almost certain there's a mathematical mapping of random hopping onto random on-site energies.... let me check that

Comment: In the literature, tunneling disorder is often called "off-diagonal disorder" and it can indeed induce localization. There are lots of papers that discuss this, here's an example experimental one with a pretty good intro (open access): https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-19-14-13636

Comment: Following the literature mentioned by @Rococo I've found [Off-diagonal disorder in one-dimensional systems](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.24.5698). It seems that the localization caused by off-diagonal disorder behaves slightly different with the Anderson localization.

Comment: It actually has been studied, here is a link to the paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2101